# Über die Verwendung von „Epizentrum“ für den Corona-Ausbruchsort

Tags: word-usage

*Epizentrum* wird [aktuell](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/corona-xi-wuhan-101.html) im übertragenen Sinne für den Ausbruchsort der Corona-Epidemie verwendet. Dahinter ist eine Logik, die ich nicht verstehe. In der Geologie bezeichnet *Epizentrum* die Projektion auf der Erdoberfläche des tatsächlichen Erbnebenherds (Hypozentrum), wie [dieses Bild](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Epicentrum-hypocentrum-schema.png) auf Niederländisch erklärt.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Epizentrum) gibt auch solches Beispiel: *Das Epizentrum der Finanzkrise*.

Worauf wird es jeweils projektiert?

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach wird hier die Eigenschaft *das Gebiet mit der größten Schadensdichte* umgetopft.

Comment: ...für welches *Zentum*  vielleicht reichen würde, meinetwegen *Hypozentrum*, wenn man unbedingt die Epidemie mit einem Erdbeben vergleichen will. Die Notwendigkeit von *Epi-* sehe ich nur nicht.

Comment: Siehe meine Antwort... Hypozentrum wäre vermutlich "richtiger", aber diesen Begriff kennt kaum jemand, Epizentrum dagegen ist sehr geläufig, und erregt die gewünschte Aufmerksamkeit / Wirkung

Comment: I doubt that the journalist was aware of the meaning of "epicentre" in seismics and structural dynamics and the alliteration of Epi-..Epi.. was more appealing than scientific correctness. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Du findest im Duden die folgende Wortherkunft:

> **Herkunft INFO**
>   zu griechisch epíkentros = über dem Mittelpunkt

In der übertragenen Bedeutung wird dabei das *über* einfach unterschlagen: Epizentrum wird im Sinne von Zentrum verwendet.

Die Zusatzbedeutung von *Epizentrum* gegenüber *Zentrum* kommt dabei weniger von der Lokation *über* dem eigentlichen Zentrum, sondern soll die *naturgewaltähnliche* Eigenschaft des Ereignisses darstellen: Genau wie ein Erdbeben ist die Finanzkrise aus dem Dudenbeispiel oder eben die Coronaepidemie (scheinbar/gefühlt) nicht aufzuhalten.

In diesem Sinne wird *Epizentrum* meist für negative Großereignisse verwendet, es schwingt immer ein wenig Angst oder zumindest Respekt mit, wenn man vom Epizentrum spricht.

Comment: Viel interessanter ist ja die Herkunft von _κέντρον_: der "Stachel" eines Zirkels...

Comment: To somebody with a geoscience background it can also mean something very small, banal, happening at high frequency all day long, just because there are so many earthquakes every day (https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/) and each has its epicentre.

Comment: I never heard any German native speaker use "Epizentrum" as something small or banal...

Comment: Yep, da gibt's eine Diskrepanz zwischen der originären Wortbedeutung und der alltäglichen Anwendung. Ähnlich wie bei "Quantensprung", in alltäglicher Anwendung ein großer Sprung/systemische Umwälzung , in der Physik etwas ganz, ganz Kleines.

Comment: Ich verstehe hier Epizentrum so, dass es der Punkt ist, von dem es ausging, nicht unbedingt der Mittelpunkt oder Schwerpunkt der Verbreitung. Bei Corona fällt das aber noch zusammen - soweit man auf einer Kugeloberfläche überhaupt ein Zentrum finden kann. Primär ist es ja nach Westen gewandert (Iran, Italien).

Comment: @a_donda wobei genaugenommen in der Physik das *entscheidende* Merkmal eines Quantensprunges nicht die sehr geringe Größe ist, sondern der unmittelbare Wechsel von einem Zustand in den anderen, ohne dass "unterwegs" irgendwelche Zwischenzustände eingenommen werden (die oftmals gar nicht existieren).